# How to run a command for each group in a column of a datframe?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like the following:

```
df <- structure(list(StudyID = c("Australia", "Australia", "Australia", 
"Australia", "Australia", "Australia", "Australia", "Australia", 
"Australia", "Australia", "Australia", "Australia", "Australia", 
"Australia", "Australia", "Australia", "Newzealand", "Newzealand", 
"Newzealand", "Newzealand"), variable_control = c("Mathew", "Mathew", 
"Mathew", "Mathew", "Simp", "Simp", "Simp", "Simp", "hutten", 
"hutten", "hutten", "hutten", "AB", "AB", "AB", "AB", "Mathew", 
"Mathew", "Mathew", "Mathew"), mean_control = c(103.125, 103.125, 
103.125, 103.125, 3.20026104175422, 3.20026104175422, 3.20026104175422, 
3.20026104175422, 0.655931978647405, 0.655931978647405, 0.655931978647405, 
0.655931978647405, 5.6147916190302, 5.6147916190302, 5.6147916190302, 
5.6147916190302, 86.3478260869565, 86.3478260869565, 86.3478260869565, 
86.3478260869565), sd_control = c(14.0136837888306, 14.0136837888306, 
14.0136837888306, 14.0136837888306, 0.278705816120361, 0.278705816120361, 
0.278705816120361, 0.278705816120361, 0.0899465623045049, 0.0899465623045049, 
0.0899465623045049, 0.0899465623045049, 6.28461426690684, 6.28461426690684, 
6.28461426690684, 6.28461426690684, 22.9900629657485, 22.9900629657485, 
22.9900629657485, 22.9900629657485), n_control = c(16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L), se_control = c(3.50342094720765, 
3.50342094720765, 3.50342094720765, 3.50342094720765, 0.0696764540300902, 
0.0696764540300902, 0.0696764540300902, 0.0696764540300902, 0.00821096019070354, 
0.00821096019070354, 0.00821096019070354, 0.00821096019070354, 
1.62268042620452, 1.62268042620452, 1.62268042620452, 1.62268042620452, 
3.38969985579422, 3.38969985579422, 3.38969985579422, 3.38969985579422
), lowCI_control = c(95.6576350141697, 95.6576350141697, 95.6576350141697, 
95.6576350141697, 3.05174919547557, 3.05174919547557, 3.05174919547557, 
3.05174919547557, 0.6396734573882, 0.6396734573882, 0.6396734573882, 
0.6396734573882, 2.13448824216196, 2.13448824216196, 2.13448824216196, 
2.13448824216196, 79.5206201201125, 79.5206201201125, 79.5206201201125, 
79.5206201201125), hiCI_control = c(110.59236498583, 110.59236498583, 
110.59236498583, 110.59236498583, 3.34877288803287, 3.34877288803287, 
3.34877288803287, 3.34877288803287, 0.67219049990661, 0.67219049990661, 
0.67219049990661, 0.67219049990661, 9.09509499589843, 9.09509499589843, 
9.09509499589843, 9.09509499589843, 93.1750320538006, 93.1750320538006, 
93.1750320538006, 93.1750320538006), Variable_test = c("Mathew", 
"Simp", "hutten", "AB", "Mathew", "Simp", "hutten", "AB", "Mathew", 
"Simp", "hutten", "AB", "Mathew", "Simp", "hutten", "AB", "Mathew", 
"Simp", "hutten", "AB"), mean_test = c(94.85, 3.11469350939242, 
0.638430601983837, 6.91683472226622, 94.85, 3.11469350939242, 
0.638430601983837, 6.91683472226622, 94.85, 3.11469350939242, 
0.638430601983837, 6.91683472226622, 94.85, 3.11469350939242, 
0.638430601983837, 6.91683472226622, 86.0222222222222, 2.6390595091832, 
0.759731493048648, 0.73921233900569), sd_test = c(17.2909316055982, 
0.202930255027022, 0.0919447770686176, 8.14939209465999, 17.2909316055982, 
0.202930255027022, 0.0919447770686176, 8.14939209465999, 17.2909316055982, 
0.202930255027022, 0.0919447770686176, 8.14939209465999, 17.2909316055982, 
0.202930255027022, 0.0919447770686176, 8.14939209465999, 21.4163158796882, 
0.451677388306635, 0.138197141547272, 0.908654293596164), n_test = c(20L, 
20L, 190L, 21L, 20L, 20L, 190L, 21L, 20L, 20L, 190L, 21L, 20L, 
20L, 190L, 21L, 45L, 45L, 990L, 45L), se_test = c(3.86636984644171, 
0.0453765844931791, 0.00667037520849417, 1.77834314960258, 3.86636984644171, 
0.0453765844931791, 0.00667037520849417, 1.77834314960258, 3.86636984644171, 
0.0453765844931791, 0.00667037520849417, 1.77834314960258, 3.86636984644171, 
0.0453765844931791, 0.00667037520849417, 1.77834314960258, 3.1925558756394, 
0.0673320896102137, 0.00439219348020005, 0.135454184568538), 
    lowCI_test = c(86.7575949081585, 3.01971922654131, 0.625272652671813, 
    3.20727591549959, 86.7575949081585, 3.01971922654131, 0.625272652671813, 
    3.20727591549959, 86.7575949081585, 3.01971922654131, 0.625272652671813, 
    3.20727591549959, 86.7575949081585, 3.01971922654131, 0.625272652671813, 
    3.20727591549959, 79.5880486308587, 2.50336059906323, 0.751112403965226, 
    0.466222367603537), hiCI_test = c(102.942405091841, 3.20966779224354, 
    0.651588551295861, 10.6263935290328, 102.942405091841, 3.20966779224354, 
    0.651588551295861, 10.6263935290328, 102.942405091841, 3.20966779224354, 
    0.651588551295861, 10.6263935290328, 102.942405091841, 3.20966779224354, 
    0.651588551295861, 10.6263935290328, 92.4563958135858, 2.77475841930317, 
    0.768350582132071, 1.01220231040784)), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to run the following command (from package metafor) on this dataframe df with a condition:

```
my_data <- escalc(n1i = n_control, n2i = n_test, m1i = mean_control, m2i = mean_test, 
    sd1i = sd_control, sd2i = sd_test, data = df, measure = "SMD", 
    append = TRUE)
```

I want to run the command 4 times for four different subsets from the dataframe (df). First, it will run on a subset dtaframe that will contain variable column value Mathew only and get an output. Next it will run on a dataframe subset that will contain variable column value AB only and get an output and so on..

Thanks in advance,
DC7

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split()` and then `lapply()`. This will return a list with an entry for each distinct value of `variable_control`:

```
split_data <- split(df, df$variable_control)


lapply(split_data, function(subset) {
  metafor::escalc(n1i = n_control, n2i = n_test, m1i = mean_control, m2i = mean_test, 
                  sd1i = sd_control, sd2i = sd_test, data = subset, measure = "SMD", 
                  append = TRUE)
})
```